# SQL Execution Time Variation between Environments

Tags: php, sql, environment, execution

We have a PHP web interface which calls a stored procedure which is taking excessively long on our live environment.  I have restored all our information to the DEV env to replicate but it seems that the query takes less that a few seconds to complete on dev what takes atleast 90 seconds on live.  I am out of ideas as to how this could be.  Also, viewing the activity monitor on live env shows that it flags the procedure call as an expensive query but not on DEV.  Does anyone have any useful insight into this variation in execution times between Environments for the same data?  Both php versions are the same as well as the data within the databases.  There is no resource governor on either database dictating priority based on user groups either.  I'm out of Ideas, any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: are your sql server settings the same on both environments?

Comment: Maximum Server memory is considerably less on the Live Server, I'm not sure if this could have something to do with it?

Comment: If you want to post your query and table structure we can help you try to get it to execute faster, other then that you probably are being limited by server resources.